# validate wordpress user login from database using python

Tags: python, wordpress, hash

I'm building a websocket based chat room in tornado where the main site runs wordpress. I want to allow the wordpress users to login to the chat with the same username and password. Hence, I would like to query the wordpress database using python and validate the provided username and password.

What I would like to know is what wordpress uses to hash the password?

(I'm aware of XMLRPC APIs which I would like to avoid)

Answer (score 8):

Wordpress uses php crypt function and can be decrypted in Python using [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/index.html).
Here is the code:

```
from passlib.hash import phpass
phpass.verify("password", "wordpress hash")
```

I've used it on Wordpress 2.8 and PHP 5.3.6 and it worked well.

Comment: Works for Wordpress 6.2 with PHP 8.0